# Property deleter is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I'm trying to use property decorators and performing basic operations while doing this getting error as well as facing problem with deleter and not getting expected output from code.

```
class Numbers(object):
    Multiplier = 4
    def __init__(self, x, y):
          self._x = x
          self._y = y

    def add(self):
        return self._x + self._y

    @classmethod
    def multiply(cls, a):
        return a*cls.Multiplier

    @staticmethod
    def subtract(b,c):
        return b-c

    @property
    def values(self):
        return "(%d,%d)" % (self._x, self._y)

    @values.setter
    def values(self, value1, value2):
        self._x = value1
        self._y = value2

    @values.deleter
    def values(self):
        print('deleting')
        del self._x
        del self._y

val = Numbers(2,4)

print(val.values)
print(val._x)
print(val._y)
print(val.multiply(5))
print(val.subtract(8,2))
print(val.add())
val.values = (34,45)
print(val.values)
del (val.values)
print(val.values)
```

Comment: The problem is with the *setter*, surely? It should take a single argument, the two-tuple of x and y values. E.g. you could make the setter `def values(self, (value1, value2)):`, although that isn't compatible with Python 3.x. But note that you should give a [mcve], not just *"getting error as well as facing problem"*.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. edited code and still has error  "AttributeError: 'Numbers' object has no attribute '_x' " @jonrsharpe

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen, what did you expect when you accessed the attribute again after explicitly deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code. The deleter is actually deleting the variables from attributes as one would expect, but this is not what you probably want since you try to display them after deleting.

So, instead of actually deleting the variables, maybe you want to replace them with a `0` or `None` instead.

```
@values.deleter
def values(self):
    print('deleting')
    self._x = None
    self._y = None
```

Another option that could make your code more straightforward is to not use the `del` keyword but instead make a "clear" function and use like `val.clear()`

The second issue is with the setter function since it is expecting 2 variables but this cannot be done with the `val.values = something` expression. So I advise you to use the following format:

```
@values.setter
def values(self, values):
    value1, value2 = values
    self._x = value1
    self._y = value2
```

And you would store the values like this:

```
val.values = (3, 5)
```